# Reading converted rss to json file with chart.js not working

Tags: javascript, php, json, rss, chart.js

I'm trying to fix something which, in my mind should work ^_^

I have this PHP code:

```
<?php

class XmlToJson {

    public static function Parse ($url) {

        $fileContents= file_get_contents($url);

        $fileContents = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t"), '', $fileContents);

        $fileContents = trim(str_replace('"', "'", $fileContents));

        $simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($fileContents);

        $json = json_encode($simpleXml);

        return $json;

    }

}

?>
```

Here I read out my Xml(RSS feed) and make a Json out of it.

In my showfeed.php I have this code:

```
<?php

include 'encode.php';

$json = XmlToJson::Parse("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="json">
<?php
echo $json;
?>
</div>
                <div id="chartCanvas">
                    <canvas id="canvas" height="600" width="600"></canvas>
                    <canvas id="canvas2" height="600" width="600"></canvas>
                    <br>
                </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myData = [document.getElementById("json")];
var myData2 = [document.getElementById("json")];


                    Array.prototype.mapProperty = function(property) {
                                        return this.map(function (obj) {
                                            return obj[property];
                                        });

                                    };

            // Example: myData.mapProperty('rank') to get an array of all ranks 
                    lineChartData = {
                    labels: myData.mapProperty('title'),
                     datasets : [
                       {
                            label: "My First dataset",
                            fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                            strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                            pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                            pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                            pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                            data : myData.mapProperty(12)
                        }
                                ]
               };
                    lineChartData2 = {
                    labels : myData2.mapProperty('v'),
                     datasets : [
                       {
                            label: "My First dataset",
                            fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                            strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                            pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                            pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                            pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                            data : myData2.mapProperty('eid')
                        }
                                ]
               };


                window.onload = function()
                {
                    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
                    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData);
                    var ctx2 = document.getElementById("canvas2").getContext("2d");
                    window.myLine2 = new Chart(ctx2).Line(lineChartData2);
                }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not hiding the Echo $json so I can see if it still works, else I'll just put the div on hidden.

But what i'm trying to fix is, to echo the `$json`, then I want `var myData en myData2` to have the value of the Json. From here on I try to create an array out of the Json so I can use it to draw the chart. And if this works I figured I can use for instance the title's as labels in the chart and a number from the Json as data.

But I'm either making it way too difficult and there might be an easier way, or I made a mistake in my code or thinking.

So what I want to do is: Read an RSS feed and use specific info to create a Chart.js. I figured this is easiest when turning the RSS into Json, but that might just be me.
But with this code all I get is an empty chart, so how can I read the Json variable I made and actually use the titles from the RSS as Labels?

Hopefully someone here can help. (the plugin for the charts is Chart.js)

**EDIT**
My $jsone echo's this:

```
{"@attributes":{"version":"2.0"},"channel":{"title":"CNN.com - Top Stories","link":"http:\/\/edition.cnn.com\/index.html?eref=edition","description":"CNN.com delivers up-to-the-minute news and information on the latest top stories, weather, entertainment, politics and more.","language":"en-US","copyright":"Copyright 2015 Cable News Network LP, LLLP.","pubDate":"Wed, 14 Jan 2015 14:03:23 EST","ttl":"10","image":{"title":"CNN.com - Top Stories","link":"http:\/\/edition.cnn.com\/index.html?eref=edition","url":"http:\/\/i.cdn.turner.com\/cnn\/.e\/img\/1.0\/logo\/cnn.logo.rss.gif","width":"144","height":"33","description":"CNN.com delivers up-to-the-minute news and information on the latest top stories, weather, entertainment, politics and more."},"item":[{"title":"Al Qaeda affiliate claims Charlie Hebdo killings","guid":"http:\/\/edition.cnn.com\/2015\/01\/14\/europe\/charlie-hebdo-france-attacks\/index.html","link":"http:\/\/edition.cnn.com\/2015\/01\/14\/europe\/charlie-hebdo-france-attacks\/index.html?eref=edition","description":"Al Qaeda in the Arabian Peninsula claims responsibility for the attack at France's Charlie Hebdo satirical newspaper in which 12 people died. More than 50 legal cases are opened against people in France for allegedly expressing support for terrorism since the massacre.","pubDate":"Wed, 14 Jan 2015 11:17:32 EST"},{"title":"What is al Qaeda in the Arabian Peninsula?","guid":"http:\/\/edition.cnn.com\/2015\/01\/14\/middleeast\/yemen-al-qaeda-arabian-peninsula\/index.html","link":"http:\/\/edition.cnn.com\/2015\/01\/14\/middleeast\/yemen-al-qaeda-arabian-peninsula\/index.html?eref=edition","description":"A leader of al Qaeda in the Arabian Peninsula says it carried out the Hebdo massacre. What do we know about the Islamist group?","pubDate":"Wed, 14 Jan 2015 11:22:26 EST"},{"title":"Al Qaeda desperate not to be eclipsed by ISIS?","guid":"http:\/\/edition.cnn.com\/2015\/01\/14\/europe\/al-qaeda-attack-claim-analysis\/index.html","link":"http:\/\/edition.cnn.com\/2015\/01\/14\/europe\/al-qaeda-attack-claim-analysis\/index.html?eref=edition","description":"AQAP's claims of responsibility for the Charlie Hebdo attack is remarkably complex and hints at the messy rivalry perhaps engulfing the jihadi world, writes CNN's Nick Paton Walsh.","pubDate":"Wed, 14 Jan 2015 12:28:45 EST"},{"title":"Mixed response to new Mohammed cover","guid":"http:\/\/edition.cnn.com\/2015\/01\/13\/living\/muslims-respond-hebdo\/index.html","link":"http:\/\/edition.cnn.com\/2015\/01\/13\/living\/muslims-respond-hebdo\/index.html?eref=edition","description":"The image of Mohammed on the new cover of Charlie Hebdo has elicited a mixed reaction from Muslims, from wariness and appreciation to annoyance and anger.","pubDate":"Wed, 14 Jan 2015 02:11:51 EST"},{"title":"How orphan brothers took wrong turn","guid":"http:\/\/edition.cnn.com\/2015\/01\/13\/world\/kouachi-brothers-radicalization\/index.html","link":"http:\/\/edition.cnn.com\/2015\/01\/13\/world\/kouachi-brothers-radicalization\/index.html?eref=edition","description":"They were the perfect targets for recruiters of jihad: two young French brothers from an immigrant family, virtually alone in the French capital.","pubDate":"Wed, 14 Jan 2015 00:23:55 EST"},{"title":"Tangled trail reveals new suspects","guid":"http:\/\/edition.cnn.com\/2015\/01\/13\/europe\/france-charlie-hebdo-attack-trail\/index.html","link":"http:\/\/edition.cnn.com\/2015\/01\/13\/europe\/france-charlie-hebdo-attack-trail\/index.html?eref=edition","description":"Investigators follow leads taking then from a Paris newsroom to Yemen and Bulgaria as they try to work out how the attacks were planned -- and who is still at large.","pubDate":"Wed, 14 Jan 2015 13:56:20 EST"},{"title":"Astronauts scramble after alarm","guid":"http:\/\/edition.cnn.com\/2015\/01\/14\/us\/international-space-station-emergency\/index.html","link":"http:\/\/edition.cnn.com\/2015\/01\/14\/us\/international-space-station-emergency\/index.html?eref=edition","description":"A possible leak in the cooling system on the International Space Station has resulted in the evacuation of the U.S. crew from the American segment of the station to the Russian segment, NASA said Wednesday. ","pubDate":"Wed, 14 Jan 2015 10:10:45 EST"},{"title":"Turkey bans Hebdo cover online","guid":"http:\/\/edition.cnn.com\/2015\/01\/14\/world\/turkey-charlie-hebdo\/index.html","link":"http:\/\/edition.cnn.com\/2015\/01\/14\/world\/turkey-charlie-hebdo\/index.html?eref=edition","description":"A Turkish court has banned Web pages that show the new cover of Charlie Hebdo, the country''s semiofficial news agency Anadolu reported Wednesday.","pubDate":"Wed, 14 Jan 2015 10:57:27 EST"},{"title":" AirAsia plane's fuselage found","guid":"http:\/\/edition.cnn.com\/2015\/01\/14\/world\/airasia-disaster\/index.html","link":"http:\/\/edition.cnn.com\/2015\/01\/14\/world\/airasia-disaster\/index.html?eref=edition","description":"Searchers have located the fuselage of AirAsia Flight QZ8501 in the Java Sea, the head of Indonesia's search and rescue agency said Wednesday, raising the prospect that many bodies of the 162 aboard the flight that crashed last month will soon be found.","pubDate":"Wed, 14 Jan 2015 13:53:49 EST"},{"title":"Police rescue 37 babies ","guid":"http:\/\/edition.cnn.com\/2015\/01\/14\/china\/china-child-trafficking-bust\/index.html","link":"http:\/\/edition.cnn.com\/2015\/01\/14\/china\/china-child-trafficking-bust\/index.html?eref=edition","description":"Police rescued 37 babies and a 3-year-old girl after busting a child trafficking ring in eastern China's Shandong province, reported the state-run China Central Television.","pubDate":"Wed, 14 Jan 2015 11:02:46 EST"},{"title":"U.S. airports tighten security","guid":"http:\/\/edition.cnn.com\/2015\/01\/14\/us\/airport-security-aqap\/index.html","link":"http:\/\/edition.cnn.com\/2015\/01\/14\/us\/airport-security-aqap\/index.html?eref=edition","description":"The Department of Homeland Security is increasing security checks at American airports because of concerns over new bomb-making instructions released by al Qaeda in Yemen (AQAP), the terrorist group which U.S. intelligence agencies believe may have been behind the Charlie Hebdo attack in Paris, U.S. officials tell CNN.","pubDate":"Wed, 14 Jan 2015 07:53:40 EST"},{"title":"Former Spanish King faces paternity suit","guid":"http:\/\/edition.cnn.com\/2015\/01\/14\/europe\/spain-former-king-paternity-suit\/index.html","link":"http:\/\/edition.cnn.com\/2015\/01\/14\/europe\/spain-former-king-paternity-suit\/index.html?eref=edition","description":"Spain's former King Juan Carlos, 77, will face a paternity lawsuit -- by a Belgian woman alleging that he's her father -- before the nation's Supreme Court, a 12-judge panel ruled Wednesday. ","pubDate":"Wed, 14 Jan 2015 14:02:01 EST"},{"title":"Home alone children die in fire","guid":"http:\/\/edition.cnn.com\/2015\/01\/14\/us\/louisiana-children-house-fire\/index.html","link":"http:\/\/edition.cnn.com\/2015\/01\/14\/us\/louisiana-children-house-fire\/index.html?eref=edition","description":"Two children, left alone in their Louisiana home, were killed in a house fire while their mother was out getting her hair styled at a salon, authorities said. ","pubDate":"Wed, 14 Jan 2015 08:39:19 EST"},{"title":"Gay woman denied funeral request","guid":"http:\/\/edition.cnn.com\/2015\/01\/14\/us\/colorado-gay-woman-funeral-service\/index.html","link":"http:\/\/edition.cnn.com\/2015\/01\/14\/us\/colorado-gay-woman-funeral-service\/index.html?eref=edition","description":"Family and friends of a gay woman in Colorado have expressed anger at a church's refusal to show a video at her funeral that contained images of the woman kissing her partner. ","pubDate":"Wed, 14 Jan 2015 03:09:58 EST"},{"title":"Man survives fall from cruise ship","guid":"http:\/\/edition.cnn.com\/2015\/01\/13\/us\/man-overboard-cruise-rescue\/index.html","link":"http:\/\/edition.cnn.com\/2015\/01\/13\/us\/man-overboard-cruise-rescue\/index.html?eref=edition","description":"A man who fell from a Royal Caribbean cruise ship off the coast of Cozumel, Mexico, was rescued by a Disney cruise ship after passengers spotted him on the water, Mexican authorities say. ","pubDate":"Tue, 13 Jan 2015 21:27:25 EST"},{"title":"Judge: No delay in Tsarnaev trial","guid":"http:\/\/edition.cnn.com\/2015\/01\/14\/justice\/tsarnaev-trial-no-delay\/index.html","link":"http:\/\/edition.cnn.com\/2015\/01\/14\/justice\/tsarnaev-trial-no-delay\/index.html?eref=edition","description":"A federal judge on Wednesday denied a request to push back the trial of alleged Boston Marathon bomber Dzhokhar Tsarnaev, who'd requested a delay after last week's terrorist attacks in France.","pubDate":"Wed, 14 Jan 2015 10:07:51 EST"}
```

which is just a small part of the huge Json/XML file

Answer (score 0):

Basically the answer is that `document.getElementById("json")` just gives you an HTML element.  If you want the contents of that element, use `document.getElementById("json").innerHTML`.

However, the contents of `innerHTML` will be a string, not a Json object.  If you want the contents of `myData` to be a Json object rather than just text formatted to look like Json, you would need to use `JSON.parse()` on that, or just do something more like:

```
var myData = <?php echo $json; ?>;
```

OR

```
var myData = [ <?php echo $json; ?> ];
```

Not sure what the array part is for, but maybe you need it.

Comment: So I'd just place that right behind it and it would work? or do I need to remove it from the array [ ] first?

Comment: @Xereoth, See my edit. There's a little more to it that I neglected.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're pulling in the DOM element into an array?

Have you tried:  data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("json").innerHTML)

That should pull in the JSON string, and then parse it if it was properly stringified (and not an object, else you'll get an error).

Comment: Thanks, I get an error so i assume that my string isn't properly stringified ;)

Comment: If you do what developerwjk says, that's a good idea to just echo the json directly in the declaration.  Can you post the value that your echo $json is outputting?

Comment: If you wrap that in single quotes I believe it will be a valid JSON stringified object, and you should be able to use parse on it.  I'm not sure how it handles @ symbols though but I think it should be fine.

So in other words something like:
data = JSON.parse("'"+document.getElementById("json").innerHTML+"'");

Or just use Parse on the echo'd result right in the declaration like is shown above by devwjk

Comment: Okay, I assume to make it single quotes I adjust my PHP code. But it doesn't seem to work if I change it to single there. as :
$fileContents = str_replace(array('\n', '\r', '\t'), '', $fileContents);

Comment: and If i parse to the document.getElemeny it doesn't give any errors, if i parse the echo directly i get : Unexpected token o.

Comment: you could return it in the php code or just wrap the return in them.  What I mean is that your PHP return uses double quotes, which is fine, but if you wrap the ENTIRE thing in single quotes, it becomes a stringified JSON object see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify  

You're probably best just adding that on the client side though.

Comment: Unexpected token o just means it's already a JSON object.  In that case you should be pulling it in just fine.  Try developerwjk's method with just the echo.